# Browser charsets order of precedence

Tags: python, html, character-encoding

Client browsers are sending the header `HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3`.  I only serve webpages as utf8 with the correct header but browsers are posting data from forms encoded with the ISO-8859-1 charset.  My question is, will a browser always prefer charsets  in the order of its ACCEPT_CHARSET header so I can reliably write a middleware that will decode any posted data with the first entry, in this case ISO-8859-1, and encode it as utf8.

**UPDATE:**

I updated the form tag with `accept-charset="utf-8"` and I'm still seeing non-unicode characters appearing.  Is it possible that a user copy/pasting their password from somewhere else (lastpass, excel file) could be injecting non-unicode characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request header `Accept-Charset` (which may get mapped to `HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET` server-side) expresses the client’s preferences, to be used when the server is capable to serving the resource in different encodings. The server may ignore it, and often will.

If your page is UTF-8 encoded and declared as such, then any form on your page will send its data as UTF-8 encoded, unless you specify an `accept-charset` attribute. So if a browser posts data as ISO-8859-1 encoded, then this is a browser bug. However, this would need to be analyzed before drawing conclusions.

There’s an ald technique of including some special character, written using a character reference for safety, as the value of a hidden field. The server-side handler can then pick up the value of this field and detect an encoding mismatch, or even to heuristically deduce the actual encoding from the encoded form of the special character.

Comment: So I guess the browser has a bug.  It's definitely not posting the data as UTF8.  I've added accept-charset and I'm getting consistent results if I just use the browser's HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET as a pointer in case of errors.

Comment: If this happens in several browsers, there’s probably a different explanation. Do you have or can you construct a public page URL that demonstrates the problem? I cannot reconstruct it. Browsers tend to send Accept-Charset headers like the one you mention, even though the page itself and the form data transmission is UTF-8. The header depends on their configuration, not on the page. I suspect that there might be some software component (server-side) that performs code conversion before the data reaches your code.

Comment: I run on Mac and the issue seems specifically related to windows users entering characters that are subsequently being encoded in extended ascii charsets, like "E" with an acute accent being encoded as \xC9 which errors when it is then blindly treated as unicode at the server.

Comment: Does this deal with data in a *file* included via `<input type=file>`? That would explain a lot… Browsers generally send the file contents as is and do not indicate the character encoding. If you have a UTF-8 encoded form and it is used to submit a plain text file in windows-1252 encoding, then its content is sent as such, declared just as text/plain (no charset), even though contents of normal fields are UTF-8 encoded. The bad news is that in general the browser *cannot* tell the encoding, so it can neither declare it nor code-convert the data,

Comment: It does not.  There are no file uploads anywhere.

Comment: @Endophage, I see—but I learned something new. To solve your case, can you set up a demo URL, and is it possible that you check the *raw* data that arrives?

Comment: Hey, sorry I can't get a test page up easily.  However, is it possible that somebody copy/pasting their password from something like lastpass would still inject non-unicode characters?

Comment: Turns out it was Python being retarded about character encodings when concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if all browsers always prefer charset in the same specific order, but you can set the accept-charset in the form, which forces the browser to send utf-8 encoded data.

Like this:

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8"></form>
```

Comment: This should work but I've had this change live for 4 days now and I'm still getting the error.